# PHP Como pegar um valor aleatório como no rand($min, $max) porém com uma query?

Tags: php, mysql, query, random

Por exemplo, em um jogo de browser eu quero que quando o usuário clicar em atacar retorne outro usuário que tenha +- o mesmo poder de batalha que ele.

```
$select = $mysqli->query("select * from data order by rand()");
```

Dessa forma ele me retorna sempre um valor aleatório, mas o que eu quero é um valor entre x e y... algo como o rand($min, $max), porém pelo que vi, o `order by rand` não funciona dessa forma...

Alguém me da uma luz de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onde `[min]` é o número mínimo e `[max]` o máximo.

```
$select = $mysqli->query("select * from data order by rand() LIMIT [max], [min]");
```

Essa query é lenta porque o `LIMIT` vai fazer um sort, um link interessante sobre a performance de seleção de registros aleatórios: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Uma alternativa, onde `id` é uma chave única numérica:

```
$select = $mysqli->query("select * from data where id between [min] and [max] order by rand()");
```

Comment: Bacana, obrigado João! +1